# Intuitive understanding of integrating a cumulative distribution function

Tags: integration, density-function

In solving newsvendor type of problems I came to this idea of integration of the cumulative distribution function.

$$ \int_\infty^b F(x) \,dx $$

Is there an intuitive understanding of what this means? So integrating the probability density function is the probability that the value falls in the given interval. Does this integration of the cumulative distribution function have a meaning?

Comment: Are you sure it said $\displaystyle \int F(x)\,dx$ rather than $\displaystyle \int f(x)\,dx \text{ ?}$ It is more usual to use the lower-case $f$ to refer to the density function and $F$ to a cumulative distribution function.

Comment: For an explanation to be intuitive, it might help to know the context in which this arose.

Comment: It was the cumulative distribution function am sure of that. We were trying to derive a proof for 
$$E(y - D)^{+} = \int_{0}^{y}F(x)dx$$ where D is a non-negative continuous random variable.

Comment: If $F$ is the cumulative distribution function, then what were you referring to in your first sentence where you mentioned the density function.

Comment: Sincere apology from me. I have modified the question.